# struts2 web project maven build and publish which has error

Tags: java, struts2

I am revamp the struts2 web project but when run and publish to local weblogic server. It has error belows: It is found that imaging-01012005.jar is missing.
What should I do now to solve this problem??

```
    Error(s) found in module 'aeon_app_public'. Publish was cancelled. See "Problems" view for details.
        The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved at aeon_app_public
        The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library
     'C:\Users\rwhchiu\.m2\repository\com\jhlabs\imaging\01012005\imaging-01012005.jar' 
at aeon_app_public
        Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.jhlabs:imaging:jar:01012005
```

Comment: add more repositories to your project or use proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by refering to the link: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-463

```
candrews Craig Andrews added a comment - 06/16/14 07:30 PM
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAVENUPLOAD-2350 explains that com.jhlabs:imaging was renamed to com.jhlabs:filters, and that is in Maven Central.
So I suppose everyone could exclude the com.jhlabs:imaging from jcaptcha and depend on com.jhlabs:filters:2.0.235-1 instead.
Of course, it would be better if someone would upload a new version of com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha with that dependency changed.
```